# How to Fill Repeater ItemTemplate from Code Behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, itemtemplate

I have to create a repeater dynamically from code behind. I want to fill the item template of this repeater from code behind but I couldn't find any kind of object to synchronize with the item template of the repeater.

Code:

```
Repeater rpr = new Repeater();
rpr.ItemTemplate = ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create instance of ITemplate. Read this example
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240760/Dynamically-create-item-templates-server-side

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override void OnItemCreated(RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnItemCreated(e);

            if (e.Item.DataItem != null && (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
            {
                DataRowView dt = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
                if (dt.DataView.Table.Columns["IsHeading"] != null)
                {
                    if ((dt["IsHeading"].ToString()) == "true")
                    {
                        ItemHeaderContainer container = new ItemHeaderContainer();
                        ItemHeaderTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);

                        container.DataItem = e.Item.DataItem;
                        container.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Refer:
http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/658854-aspnet-repeaters-with-dynamic-itemtemplates/